# Display free disk space on selected drive on "Select Destination Location" page of Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm creating an installer using Inno Setup and my question is:

How can I add custom text labels like: "Space in your current drive : XXX Mb" and the space required number on that wizard page:

[image: Wizard Page]

It will be very cool if you can help me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GetSpaceOnDisk64`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getspaceondisk64) to query free disk space:

```pascal
var
  FreeDiskSpaceLabel: TNewStaticText;

procedure UpdateDiskSpaceLabel;
var
  Path, Path2: string;
  Free, Total: Int64;
  FreeGB: Extended;
  S: string;
begin
  Path := WizardDirValue;
  { Installation path will be typically absent, }
  { so find the first parent path that really exists }
  while not DirExists(Path) do
  begin
    Path2 := RemoveBackslash(ExtractFilePath(RemoveBackslash(Path)));
    if (Path2 = '') or (Path2 = Path) then break;
    Path := Path2;
  end;
  if GetSpaceOnDisk64(Path, Free, Total) then
  begin
    FreeGB := Extended(Free) / (1024*1024*1024);
    S := Format('There is %.1n GB free space on selected drive.', [FreeGB]);
  end
    else
  begin
    S := 'Error querying free space on selected drive';
  end;
  FreeDiskSpaceLabel.Caption := S;
end;

procedure DirEditChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UpdateDiskSpaceLabel;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  FreeDiskSpaceLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  FreeDiskSpaceLabel.Parent := WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Parent;
  FreeDiskSpaceLabel.Top :=
    WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Top - WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Height - ScaleY(8);
  FreeDiskSpaceLabel.Left := WizardForm.DiskSpaceLabel.Left;

  WizardForm.DirEdit.OnChange := @DirEditChange;
  { Update for default/previous path }
  UpdateDiskSpaceLabel;
end;
```

[image]